# Creating File and Linking to Object

Tags: apex, files

I am working on replacing my attachments with Files.  I have created an apex class to create the `ContentVersion` record but I have been unable to create the `ContentDocumentLink` object to link the document to my case.  The below code creates the file, I just need some help on how I link this to the case.  How do I query for the `ContentVersion` of the newly created record and apply that to the `ContentObjectLink`?

```
 public PageReference SaveandClose() {
    system.debug('Here is the Description ' + cv.Description);
    //Get the ContentVersion RecordTypeID for ABM Case
    string CVRTID = [select id, name from recordtype where sObjectType = 'ContentVersion' and Name = 'ABM Case'].Id;

    ContentVersion v = new ContentVersion();
    v.RecordTypeId = CVRTID;
    v.versionData = file;
    v.title = cv.title;
   v.Description = cv.Description;

    v.Document_Type__c = cv.Document_Type__c;
    v.pathOnClient ='/somepath.txt';
    insert v;
    //return new PageReference('/' + v.id);
    return null;

        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ContentDocument can be queried from the ContentVersion.

```
v = [SELECT ContentDocumentId FROM ContentVersion WHERE Id = :v.Id];
ContentDocumentLink cdl = 
  new ContentDocumentLink(
    ContentDocumentId=v.ContentDocumentId,
    LinkedEntityId=caseRecord.Id, ...);
insert cdl;
```

Comment: Thanks so much!!! I appreciate your help!